# Can one domain have multiple iommu page tables in the Xen environment with VT-d

Tags: iommu

As we know, IOMMU does the remapping from GPA to HPA. When I look into the codes in xen passthrough driver, It seems that all the devices belonging to dom0 (domu is the same) share one IOMMU page table.

My current project uses Intel VT-d, and needs one separate IOMMU page table for one specified device, thus dom0 may have 2 iommu page tables in total, one is 1:1 mapping, one is my separated page table.

I wonder could this requirement be satisfied? if so, how will IOMMU do the iotlb?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the term *domain* is different from the term *domain* in Xen.

One device indeed can have one remapping structure in VT-d. And the *domain_id* in the context entry indicates the number of this remapping structure, which can be decided by YOU.

The bridge between the *domain* in Xen and the *domain_id* in context entry is one *Hash Map*.

In summary, one domain has its own P2M mapping, but the devices assigned to this domain can have different remapping structures in VT-d.